# Synergy restrict hotkey to one computer

Tags: audio, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, synergy

**Server**

Ubuntu 16.04x64

Synergy 1.8.8

**Client**

macOS 10.13.3

Synergy 1.8.8

I would like to have the media keys on my keyboard sent to the server regardless of what screen I am on.

On the client, I could not find any configuration that needed to be made to activate this.

On the server, I went to Configure Server then clicked on the Hotkeys tab. I added a new hotkey for the `keystroke(AudioMute)`. I then selected that hotkey and added a new action for it. In the configure action I have chosen the following:

**Choose the action to perform**

```
Press and release a hotkey
keystroke(AudioMute)
```

**only on these screens**

```
server screen selected
```

**This action is performed when**

```
the hotkey is pressed
```

From my understanding, this should make it so that when I press the Mute media key that it should route back to the server and execute the Mute media key. However, this does not seem to be working at all. When I press the key associated with the hotkey on the server it will mute the server. When I press the hotkey on the client machine it will mute the client.

I have tried using a modifier with the media key such as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+`AudioMute`. This did not work either. Am I missing a setting or configuration? It seems like the hotkeys may be overridden by the default actions on the client machine. I am unsure of how to further troubleshoot as I am not as familiar with macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Synergy 1.10 added this feature with the addition of the [target screen for the keystroke() action](https://github.com/symless/synergy-core/wiki/Text-Config#Actions).

```
 keystroke(key) = keystroke(key[,screens])
```

Currently it builds the options at service startup in sequential order, so if you're going to use a destination screen make sure the keystroke setting appears after the screen definition in the configuration.

```
 keystroke(AudioMute) = keystroke(AudioMute, myUbuntuServer)
 keystroke(AudioPlay) = keystroke(AudioPlay, myUbuntuServer)
```

You can set almost any key combination if you'd prefer to use CTRL+AudioMute for the server and mute to operate normally on the client:

```
 keystroke(control+AudioMute) = keystroke(AudioMute, myUbuntuServer)
```